# Get key names from the JSON

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

How can I get list of key names from following JSON? (A1, A2)

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '{
    "Model": [{
        "A1": {
            "read": [
                "jcc",
                "rdbro"
            ],
            "write": [
                "jcc"
            ]
        },
        "A2": {
            "read": [
                "jcc",
                "rdbro",
                "rdbrw"
            ],
            "write": [
                "foo"
            ]
        }
    }]
}'

SELECT *
 FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Model') AS oj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next statement should give you the key names. `Model` is a `JSON` array, so you need an additional `APPLY` operator and `OPENJSON()` call with default schema, which returns table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`:

Json data:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '{
    "Model": [{
        "A1": {
            "read": [
                "jcc",
                "rdbro"
            ],
            "write": [
                "jcc"
            ]
        },
        "A2": {
            "read": [
                "jcc",
                "rdbro",
                "rdbrw"
            ],
            "write": [
                "foo"
            ]
        }
    }]
}'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT j2.[key] 
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Model') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) j2
```

Output:

```
----
key
----
A1
A2
```